# Querying ManyToMany relationships

Tags: django, django-models

I have a bunch of stations that belong in groups. Each station can be in multiple groups. This is the model (simplified):

```
class Station(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=False, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Station " + self.name



class StationGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, primary_key=True)
    stations = models.ManyToManyField(Station)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Station group " + self.name
```

How can I get a list/queryset containing

1. stations that are not in any group
2. stations that are in N groups
3. the intersection, union and difference of N stationGroups

?

(Suggestions for better question title are welcome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in any group:

```
Station.objects.filter(stationgroup=None)
```

in N groups:

```
Station.objects.annotate(group_count=Count('stationgroup')).filter(group_count=N)
```

intersection/difference - there aren't any built-in ways of doing this. One possibility is to simply query the groups, convert them to sets and do the comparisons in Python. Or, you could write custom [query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/) to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Daniel's answer, to get objects that are in ANY of a list of groups, you do

```
Station.objects.filter(stationgroup=g1).filter(stationgroup=g2).filter(stationgroup=g3)
```

[Docs Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)